# Is it legal to create your own currency in the EU?

Tags: european-union, france, currency

In the European Union, and more particularly in France, is it legal for an association to create its own [private currency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_currency)?

Comment: like "monopoly money"? What kind of "currency" is only used "for fun"?

Comment: For internal affairs, it's an idea we've had, but the goal isn't really the point of the question, I'm just asking if it's legal

Comment: in what way is it a "currency" then?

Comment: I added a link to the Wikipedia article, essentially a token that can be created by the association, exchanged and used by the members

Comment: The key questions, I guess, would be tax and money laundering issues. If a store writes a "gift certificate" worth 1€, who is to stop two private citizens to pass one in exchange for considerations worth 1€? The problem happens if this "gift certificate" appears in the cash register and ledgers of another store.

Comment: this is what bitcoin is